# How to remove the type error associated with elements of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

A triangle number

```
number = '''3
7 4
2 4 6
8 5 9 3'''
```

To find the maximum sum from top to bottom.

```
pyramidlist = [[int(x) for x in y.split(' ')] for y in number.split('\n')]

for i in range(len(pyramidlist) - 2, -1, -1):
    for j in range(i+1):
        pyramidlist[i][j] += max(pyramidlist[i+1][j], pyramidlist[i+1][j+1])
```

I get an Error:

```
pyramidlist[i][j] += max(pyramidlist[i+1][j], pyramidlist[i+1][j+1])
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

What is pyramidlist and why I think max is not working:

```
In [183]: pyramidlist
Out[183]: [[3], [7, 4], [2, 4, 6], [8, 5, 9, 3]]

In [184]: max(pyramidlist[1][0],pyramidlist[1][1])

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-184-c42be0ee587f>", line 1, in <module>
    max(pyramidlist[1][0],pyramidlist[1][1])

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Problem: [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=18)

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Don't you just want `sum(max(el) for el in pyramidlist)`?

Comment: I need `pyramidlist[0][0]`

Comment: @reego, I I think I don't have too clear what you are asking for. Just for the record,  I haven't downvoted your question.

Comment: You probably redefined `max` by assigning to it: `max = ....` somewhere before in your code. Don't use the names of builtin functions as variable names.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille No! I did not.

Comment: The only call in the line that gives an error is the call to `max`, and as the message states, it's an `int`.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I have provided the console response to  what `pyramidlist` is and how the `max` operation on two elements of `pyramidlist` gives an error

Comment: "No! I did not." - you totally did. Type `max` on a line by itself and see what that gives you. (It'll be an int.)

Comment: @user2357112 If I assign max to a value and run the code and then remove that particular part of the code and run again. The values associated with max stays ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using IPython. All the variables you have assigned in the code/cells you executed before keep their values for the whole session.

If you did

```
max = 25
```

then

```
max(3, 4)
```

will give you

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

If you replaced one of the builtin functions by mistake, you can give it its original value back like this:

```
import builtins
max = builtins.max

max(3, 4)
# 4
```

As @user2357112 commented, a simpler way is to do

```
del max
```

which, in his own words,

> is easier and a bit more thorough. (It looks like it should make
>   things worse, but it doesn't.)

Comment: Alternatively, `del max` is easier and a bit more thorough. (It *looks* like it should make things worse, but it doesn't.)

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks, I wouldn't have thought about it, I'll add it to the answer!